# How to bail out from critical error in Application.onCreate with message

Tags: android

My application performs some basic sanity checks in `Application.onCreate`. If a critical/unrecoverable error is found, I want to bail out and not launch the application. Is it possible to do so?

At a minimum, I would want to display some kind of error message or notification to the user. Since I don't even have a `Context` I don't know how do display a `Toast`, `AlertDialog` or `Dialog`.

Comment: If you are in onCreate, you do have context, isn't it?

Comment: Your Application is also a context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to bail out and not launch the application. Is it possible to do so?

You can use:

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

> At a minimum, I would want to display some kind of error message or notification to the user.

android.app.Application, like Activity and Service, is a subclass of android.content.Context, To pop up a notification for example a Toast:

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

}
```

Comment: This works, but Toast is not being displayed as the app is killed in the next time using your recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a flag in onCreate such as unrecoverableError or some such, and then in onResume (where you do have a Context) check that flag and show the error (and exit) if necessary.